# DB2 LUW (11.5) Inserts from External Table causing row-level locking

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I am trying to do simultaneous inserts from external tables (files in csv format) in DB2 table which is truncated before starting inserts.

```
insert into dbo.TEST_DATA select * from EXTERNAL '/u03/app/TEST_DATA_1.csv' USING (DELIMITER ',' REMOTESOURCE 'JDBC')

insert into dbo.TEST_DATA select * from EXTERNAL '/u03/app/TEST_DATA_2.csv' USING (DELIMITER ',' REMOTESOURCE 'JDBC')
```

I see multiple entries as below in SYSIBMADM.LOCKS_HELD table and both queries are stuck.

```
179 db2jcc_application  DB2INST1    DBO TEST_DATA   ROW_LOCK    X   GRNT
```

Data in both external tables are completely different with no overlapping. No other process is reading data from this table, TEST_DATA

Wondering what's causing the lock as I am only doing inserts and how can I avoid this issue?

Any insight or solution is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's nothing unusual, that inserting application holds some X row locks. You should use [SYSIBMADM.MON_LOCKWAITS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0056601.html) to understand, what application is a holder of what resource, which requester is waiting for. The `HLD_APPLICATION_HANDLE` column provides you an information about the application handle of holder at least. If you need a full transaction history of each participating application, you may use event monitor for locking with history for that.

Comment: Thank you @MarkBarinstein 
Is there a way to avoid this locking? My use case is to dump data into tables from files. No application is connecting to the database, so don't care about concurrency while loading the data.

Comment: If you want to avoid something, you must understand what to avoid. You must understand, what your statements are waiting for (if any). What is the result of select from the view I provided? What are the application states (use `SELECT EVENT_STATE || '|' || EVENT_TYPE || '|' || EVENT_OBJECT AS STATE FROM TABLE(MON_GET_AGENT(NULL, NULL, <my_handle>, -2))`)?

Comment: insert into table is also done inside a transaction, so it will always lock. if you wish you can try load command: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008305.html

Comment: Thanks @MarkBarinstein I got below output:
EXECUTING|PROCESS|REQUEST
EXECUTING|PROCESS|REQUEST

SYSIBMADM.MON_LOCKWAITS showed me a lock on the table. one query is holding the lock while other waiting. These are same two queries I am executing.

Comment: Thanks @mshabou I am trying load command from remote server as file is in remote server via jdbc. Seems like load needs the file to be present on the database server. When I pass the file path from where I am executing the load command, it errors out with
SQL2036N  The path for the file, named pipe, or device 
"/u03/app/TEST_DATA_1.csv" is not valid.

Comment: Strange enough. The application status doesn't show, that one of the applications is constantly waiting on lock. Once again, edit your question and show the exact result of SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.MON_LOCKWAITS. Do you really have the same values with the only difference in monotonously increasing LOCK_WAIT_ELAPSED_TIME after a number of subsequent calls of this query?

Comment: Hi @Dev, yes load is a command, not an SQL, it need the file to be in the server or in need a db2 client, not possible with a remote JDBC. how much data do you need to load ? is it a one shot load or you will run load many times ?

Comment: That's right @MarkBarinstein it's just one entry SYSIBMADM.MON_LOCKWAITS with increasing LOCK_WAIT_ELAPSED_TIME

Comment: @mshabou I am loading data from multiple files, each having 3M+ records.